# Swift Generics Type Inference Extensions

Tags: swift, generics, swift-extensions

I am trying to build my understanding of Generics in Swift by creating a Min and Max extension for the Array class (similar to Min and Max Extension methods in C#). There may be a better way to do this, but as I said, it just to help me understand Generics.

I have created the following code:

```
extension Array {
    func max<T, U : Comparable>(f: T -> U ) -> U? {
        var maxSoFar : U? = nil
        for i in self {
            var itemValue = f(i as T)
            if(maxSoFar == nil) {
                maxSoFar = itemValue
            }
            if itemValue > maxSoFar {
                maxSoFar = itemValue
            }
        }
        return maxSoFar
    }

    func min<T, U : Comparable>(f: T -> U ) -> U? {
        var minSoFar : U? = nil
        for i in self {
            var itemValue = f(i as T)
            if(minSoFar == nil) {
                minSoFar = itemValue
            }
            if itemValue < minSoFar {
                minSoFar = itemValue
            }
        }
        return minSoFar
    }
}
```

To test, I have created a basic Person class:

```
class Person {
    var name : String
    var age : Float

    init(name: String, age: Float) {
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    }
}
```

It seems to work fine for these cases when I am explicit in the closure:

```
var maximumAge = [Person(name: "Bob", age: 42), Person(name:"Mary", age:40)]
    .max{ (p: Person) in p.age }! // Gives 42

var min = [100, 101].min{ (i: Int) in i }! // Gives 100
```

However, I cannot get it to infer the types for using the extreme shorthand case:

```
var maximumAge = [Person(name: "Bob", age: 42), Person(name:"Mary", age:40)]
    .max{ $0.age }! // Error

var min = [100, 101].min{ $0 }! // Error
```

Or the medium length:

```
var maximumAge = [Person(name: "Bob", age: 42), Person(name:"Mary", age:40)]
    .max{p in p.age }! // Error

var min = [100, 101].min{ i in i }! // Error
```

If anyone is an expert on this yet, can you let me know what I am doing wrong? I have to admit it took me a fair bit of reading and hacking to get this far!

Thanks in advance for any replies

Comment: You might be interested in my [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26228506/27779) and [gist](https://gist.github.com/Revolucent/1a8085746b950d91a0a8) to solve the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you define `max` (and `min`) like this:

```
func max<T, U : Comparable>(f: T -> U ) -> U?
```

You're actually saying that the closure `f` might take a different type than the elements in the `Array`. Since `Array` is already a generic struct `Array<T>`, you can re-use the element type `T` that it's already defined. From [the Swift language guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH26-XID_287):

> When you extend a generic type, you do not provide a type parameter
>   list as part of the extension’s definition. Instead, the type
>   parameter list from the original type definition is available within
>   the body of the extension, and the original type parameter names are
>   used to refer to the type parameters from the original definition.

So, since the element type `T` is already available to you, simply take the `T` out of the type parameter list, like so:

```
func max<U : Comparable>(f: T -> U ) -> U?
```

That guarantees that the closure `f` will take the same type `T` that the elements in the `Array` have. Then the compiler can correctly infer which types you are using in your test cases and fixes the errors you're seeing.

Comment: This also lets you get rid of the `as T` in your calls to `f()`, since `T` is now the underlying base type of the array.

Comment: Now I can also remove the cast on var itemValue = f(i as T) and simplify it to let itemValue = f(i)